# How to disable all menu tab completions in ZSH. I have the zsh-autosuggestions plugin installed, and i want that to be the only form of completions

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

So I installed zsh a few days ago, and I'm loving it. But when I type something in, it shows me the possible completion using the autosuggestions plugin, but I cannot fill it using tab, i have to use the arrow keys. Pressing tab opens a menu of possible completions and/or a list of subdirectories and files. I want to have no menu completions and the only completions to be done through the autosuggestions plugin.

I've been tinkering for a few hours trying to get this so if anyone knows how to achieve this I would appreciate some help
(debian using ohmyzsh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unload the completion system completely like this:

```bsh
zmodload -u zsh/compctl zsh/complete
bindkey '^I' forward-word
```

Instead of inserting completions, <kbd>Tab</kbd> will now accept the next word from `zsh-autosuggestions`.

---

Before you give up completely on completions, though, may I suggest you give [my `zsh-autocomplete` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) a try? It gives you Visual Studio Code -style, type-head autocompletion in Zsh. And yes, you can use both `zsh-autosuggestions` and `zsh-autocompletion` in parallel.

Comment: The auto-complete plugin is exactly what i was looking for. I use visual studio a lot so that is perfect. The first command i need some help on though, it says "zmodload: module zsh/complete is in use by another module and cannot be unloaded". Ive tried messing with it for an hour or two and cant figure it out

Comment: `zsh-autocomplete` uses `zsh`’s own completion system under the hood. So, no need to unload it.

Comment: `zmodload: module zsh/complete is in use by another module and cannot be unloaded`

Comment: `zsh/complete` can't be unloaded. It has `zsh/zle`, i.e. the line editor, as a dependency, as can be seen by running `zmodload -d zsh/complete`. `zsh/zle` can't be unloaded, and hence `zsh/complete` can't be unloaded.

Comment: @Carl You’ve understood it the wrong. If A has B as a dependency, then you cannot unload B without also unloading A. However, zle can never be unloaded in an interactive session anyway.

Comment: @KrishnanShankar You cannot unload complete without also unloading compctl, since the former is a dependency of the latter. Run the commands in my answer _exactly_ as written and it will work.